# plot smooth cycle in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a Problem with the plotting of smooth cycles.

For example, when I try to plot this:

```
\draw plot [smooth cycle] coordinates{(0,-1),(1,-1),(2,0),(4,1),(5,0),(3,-1)};
```

I get this error message:  ! Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate.See the tikz package documentation for explanation.

however, a different set of coordinates like:

```
\draw plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (3,1) (1,0) (2,-1)};
```

works perfectly fine. Could you help me find what the difference between the two sets of coordinates is, and why I cannot plot what I want?
Tank you very much!

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tikz}  

\begin{document}  

\begin{tikzpicture}  
\draw plot [smooth cycle] coordinates{(0,-1),(1,-1),(2,0),(4,1),(5,0),(3,-1)};  
\draw plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (3,1) (1,0) (2,-1)};  
\end{tikzpicture}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: can you show a compilable example?

Comment: i hope there are no packages missing...?

Comment: No comma between coordinate pairs. `\draw plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(0,-1) (1,-1) (2,0) (4,1) (5,0) (3,-1)};`

Comment: @M-S-R, these things happen. Your welcome.